# How to jump to page on on button click?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascal

I need a simple thing: have advance and normal installation buttons. For normal case it is all simple - I used default next button with some logic on `NextButtonClick` to set a condition variable and skeep some pages using `ShouldSkipPage` . Yet for advanced setup I created a new button and all I need it to do on click is to open next installer page:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID : Integer);
begin
if CurPageID = wpWelcome then begin
    AdvancedButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
    AdvancedButton.Caption := 'Advanced Install';
    AdvancedButton.Left := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + 10;
    AdvancedButton.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height + 88;
    AdvancedButton.Parent := WizardForm.NextButton.Parent;
    # AdvancedButton.OnClick :=  What shall I call to open say next page (or some page by given PageID value)
    end
    else begin
    AdvancedButton.Visible := False;
    end;

end;
```

So What shall I call to open say next page (or some page by given PageID value) on my button click (could not find any NextPage or some SetPage function in Inno API)?

Comment: OT: as first after control creation set the `Parent` property to the control. It's better to do so because you may want to apply control alignment by its parent and you may mistakenly add such line before the parent is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Direct jump to page" in Inno Setup.
All you need is to quietly skip certain pages in 'Advanced mode'.

Simply do the same as in regular installer. Set one variable for holding 'Advanced mode'. After clicking the Advance button:

```
[Code]
var
  IsAdvanced: Boolean;

procedure AdvancedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IsAdvanced := True;
  WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  AdvancedButton: TNewButton;
begin
  // not necessary; just for sure
  IsAdvanced := False;
  // create the button
  AdvancedButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AdvancedButton.Caption := 'Advanced Install';
  AdvancedButton.Left := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Left + 10;
  AdvancedButton.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height + 88;
  AdvancedButton.Parent := WizardForm.NextButton.Parent;
  AdvancedButton.OnClick := @AdvancedButtonClick;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // the <page where you want to end up> fill with the wizard page constant
  // of the page where you want to end up, e.g. wpReady
  Result := IsAdvanced and (PageID <> <page where you want to end up>);
end;
```

With this logic you can simulate quiet 'jump' to certain page.

Comment: Note that pages are not necessarily shown in numeric id order, so this may result in skipping unintended pages.  Also, it needs to **not** skip the page that the IsAdvanced choice itself is on, otherwise the user might be surprised when they click Back to change their mind.

Comment: Would it not require user to click on advanced and on next? I would love to make him click only on one button - this is my main point.

Comment: Yes, it would. However you can simulate the next button click as I've shown in my edit (Slappy, I hope you don't mind about my intercept :-)

Answer (score 0):

`WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(nil);` isn't recommend as it takes the maximum page you ever opened. Usually its the same as your page shows, but if you manipulate their order, it differs!

As for the build-in pages, there exist always two different names - the ID one and the code-equivalent. Look at this page https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=wizardpages and append the word "Page", leaving out all the spaces.

E.g.: wpSelectTasks = *SelectTasks***Page**

```
procedure SettingsChangeButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Show;
end;

procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  SettingsChangeButton: TButton;
begin
  CustomPage1 := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, CustomMessage('CustomTitle'), CustomMessage('CustomSubTitle'));
  SettingsChangeButton := TButton.Create(CustomPage1);
  SettingsChangeButton.OnClick := @SettingsChangeButtonOnClick;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateTheWizardPages;
end;
```

Especially the line: `WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.Show;` should be changed to the page you would jump to.
If you have a custom page or you want +1 page, just use `PostMessage(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle, 245,0,0);` and -1 with `PostMessage(WizardForm.BackButton.Handle, 245,0,0);` PostMessage actually does the same job as if you click the button with the mouse, not to compare with SendMessage or OnClick(nil).

It doesn't matter, whether the site is skipped by default. If you call it like this, it will be visible.
Just keep in mind, always testing your installer, as manipulating the order of pages might result in unwanted site effects such as errors or endless loops.